# How to add a role filter on request combined with OAuth

Tags: java, oauth, filter, jersey, role

I would like to develop a portal which contains some modules
The portal and each module consume data provided by a webservice based on Jersey and secured with OAuth 1.0

For the moment I have almost implement the OAuth provider

A user can connect to the portal and access to a module

Each app or module has a specific access token to consume resource

What I want to do is to add a role implementation

For example for the module1, the user can have 2 roles (role1 and role2) but can't use the 2 roles in parallel

First the user uses the access (module1 / user1 / role1) and he will have a token and later the user uses the access (module1 / user1 / role2) and he will have an other token

Depending on the role, I would like to filter the request with a RolesAllowed annotation for example

I have read this article: http://objecthunter.congrace.de/tinybo/blog/articles/89

When the user is authenticated to the web service I could persist in a database the username, and the role used for the module and the RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory could use the realm to check if the user is in the role and can access to the resource

But can I by-passed the auth method?

Anyway I really need your help to implement this role filter thing

I will try to give you more details if you need

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Jersey oauth filter sets the security context based on what access token was used. You just have to make sure your custom implementation of the oauth provider assigns a token with the right return values from the isInRole() method when called with various roles. The role for a given token can be established during the token authorization flow (e.g. the client can request a particular role using a custom parameter that it passes to the server when requesting a request token (this gets passed in the parameters parameter to the provider.newRequestToken() method).

The security context that the oauth filter sets will delegate to the token isInRole() method when determining the roles - and the RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory relies on the security context. So, everything should work as expected if OAuthToken.isInRole() returns the right value. Are you facing any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but I was facing similar issue. In my case I solved it exactly the same way as Martin described. During token authorisation I set allowed roles:

```
String verifier = provider.authorizeToken(token, sContext.getUserPrincipal(), roles);
```

where provider is @Context DefaultOAuthProvider, token is DefaultOAuthProvider.Token and roles is a Set of roles I want to allow the access by this token:

```
Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
roles.add("someRole");
```

Then in my service I just use a @Context SecurityContext method isUserInRole("someRole") which gives me true in case the user is in specified role and false if not:

```
if (sContext.isUserInRole("someRole")) {
     ....
}
```

Hope it will help somebody.